# Adding external assembly references to Azure Function on Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, azure, visual-studio-2017, .net-assembly, azure-functions

I'm trying to add a dependency on an external assembly to an Azure Function developed and published from Visual Studio 2017.
On Azure Functions developed on the Portal, I can add dependencies as as normal using #r and referencing a .dll in the Function directory.
In Visual Studio, I get "the reference is invalid or unsupported" if I try to reference the same .dll on my local machine (which makes sense), and it doesn't let me reference assemblies not present on my local machine but present in the Function directory (which also makes sense).
So the question is, how can I add assembly references to an Azure Function developed on Visual Studio? Am I missing something obvious?

(N.B. there are other reasons prohibiting just copying the function over and developing it entirely on the Portal, so that isn't an option)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Function App in Visual Studio 2017 is just a Class Library project. You should be able to reference other assemblies the usual way for such projects: either by adding a NuGet package, or via `Add Reference` dialog.

Comment: Adding the dependency as a NuGet package works. In this case it didn't solve my problem but in most cases it would.

Comment: For me it says under 'Assemblies' : Targeting .NETStandard 2.0 but also "No framework assemblies were found on the machine!"

Comment: I have azure functions developed in Visual studio and when I reference another assembly that I've created, the azure functions run fine locally, but then when I upload it, it doesn't work. I can see the referenced assembly has been uploaded when I look through Kudu.